# Dependency injection : how do i resolve multiple instances at runtime?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I am using `Simple Injector` for my injection fun.

As far as, I understand I only register and resolve with my container on my bootstrapper project.

So I have this code in my console application :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Container container = ComposeRoot();

    var controller = container.GetInstance<IBussinesLogicController>();
    controller.Execute();

    Console.WriteLine("Started");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Container ComposeRoot()
{
    var container = new Container();

    //Bussines Logic controllers.
    container.Register<IBussinesLogicController, BussinesLogicController>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    container.Register<IStationController, StationController>(Lifestyle.Transient);

    //Data Access controllers.
    container.Register<IDataAccessController, DataAccessController>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    container.Register<IDirectoryStructureController, DirectoryStructureController>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

    //Shared controllers.
    container.Register<ILogger, LoggerController>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

    container.Verify();

    return container;
}
```

This will resolve my businesslogic controller and call Execute.

Now in execute I want to resolve 10 new instances of `IStationController` and add them to a list.

```cs
var stations = new List<IStationController>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //Resolve IStationController here...
    //IStationController station = diContainer.GetInstance<IStationController>();
    //station.StationName = $"Station {i}";
    //stations.Add(station);
}
```

How can i do this properly, since my Business Logic project does not and is not allowed a reference to the dependency container?

I can resolve this easily by adding the dependency to the container but am afraid i am not following the correct patterns.

My solution layout is as follows :

- Class Library (DAL)
- Class Library (BLL) <- IBussinesLogicController
- Class Library (Models)
- Class Library (Logger)
- Console Application (ConsoleApp6) <- ComposeRoot()

Please let me know what the right approach is to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Your business logic cannot call a reference a DI container, important is to understand where is `StationController` required in Business or some other layer. You can create a Factory, which internally invokes the DI container

Comment: Hi Mrinal Kamboj  Ok but this factory would again be in my bussineslogic implementation and would not have a reference to the DI container, can you please show by example what you mean. At this point only the bootstrap application (console application) has a reference to the DI container.

Comment: Check my answer, only Factory has a reference to the DI container, not the caller / business layer / console application

Comment: What is `StationController` for a type of object? I assume contains application behavior (since you registered it in the controller), but I noticed that it contains a mutable property named `StationName`, which is odd for a component. Components should typically be immutable and they shouldn't require [runtime data (a name) during construction](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). Can you elaborate on what `StationController` is, why it has a name, and why you create a list of them? Is it a component, or something else, such as an entity or DTO?

Comment: @Steven please do note that all of this is test-code to learn the Simple Injector framework, to elaborate, the StationController is a controller which will read out a certain directory and consume (parse) any xml files inside, how would you inject this station-name information into this class ?

Comment: That depends on how it is used. Can you show the StationController code in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a [factory delegate](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates) and use it in your class.

Register the delegate as follows:

```
container.Register<IStationController, StationController>(Lifestyle.Transient);
container.RegisterSingleton<Func<IStationController>>(
    () => container.GetInstance<IStationController>());
```

And inject it to your `BussinesLogicController` constructor:

```
public BussinesLogicController (Func<IStationController> stationControllerFacrtory)
```

And you use it in the loop:

```
List<IStationController> stations = new List<IStationController>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //Resolve IStationController here...
    IStationController station = this.stationControllerFactory.Invoke();
    station.StationName = $"Station {i}";
    stations.Add(station);
}
```

Comment: This would still need caller of the `BussinesLogicController` have a reference to DI container, as the `GetInstance` is injected, I am not sure how much would that work with OP's requirements, but a fairly decent way to accept a delegate and invoke to get an object

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, Thats not true, this is done by the container automatically. there is no need to inject the container.

Comment: Hi @OfirWinegarten, this works without having a reference to the DI container but is this the ultimate solution to the problem or just a hack to make it work ? Is this how you would approach this problem in production code ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Alright you are directly injecting in the MVC controller, using DI framework, but that's based on the assumption that Controller and the business logic are same class, what if Controller now calls a business layer component separately

Comment: @Christophe, If you have the need to create objects from within your `BusinessLogicController` then you need a factory, and this is how it's implemented with SimpleInjector. I would use it in production.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, This registers a delegate. you can inject this delegate into whatever class that requires it, like you do with any other type

Comment: Thanks @OfirWinegarten i have accepted this answer as the solution it does provide a flexible way to create factories for my DI resolved instances, also thanks to MrinalKamboj for contributing to my question.

Comment: Cool +1 I like the approach, though the page you have linked, says it is better avoid this strategy, as its a design smell, it may serve OP but not sure about the durability of such a design. Copying from same link:
Warning: We personally think that allowing to register Func<T> delegates by default is a design smell. The use of Func<T> delegates makes your design harder to follow and your system harder to maintain and test.

Comment: Welcome @Christophe, though have a hard look at your exact design requirements

Comment: @Christophe, I have a question as you implement:
`public BusinesLogicController (Func<IStationController> stationControllerFacrtory)`
How would you invoke BusinesLogicController to automatically inject the `Func<IStationController>`, until and unless you have MVC, for which Simple Injector has a better mechanism

Comment: @MrinalKamboj the Func<IStationController> stationControllerFacrtory is injected by the Simple Injector library, after registering it i dont need to do anything, from the constructor i store it in a private variable inside the class, please elaborate as i am afraid i am not understanding your question.

Comment: @Christophe Can you please paste your working code as an edit to the original question for more clarity regarding the implemented use case. In general constructor injection is default by DI framework, but you need to create an object of the hosted wrapper, something like:

`container.GetInstance<BusinessLogicWrapper>()`, here `BusinessLogicWrapper` internally contains injectable, IStationController

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing the documentation for the [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io), have a look at the following [link](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html), which details the seamless implementation of the Dependency Injection for the ASP.Net MVC, where the DI framework takes care of resolving the dependency at the run-time. I am making an assumption that you are working with an MVC controller

Pasting the relevant code and customizing:

**Application Start event**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc;

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication {

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // 1. Create a new Simple Injector container
        var container = new Container();

        // 2. Configure the container (register)
        // See below for more configuration examples
        container.Register<IStationController, StationController>(Lifestyle.Transient);

        // 3. Optionally verify the container's configuration.
        container.Verify();

        // 4. Store the container for use by the application
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
            new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

**Basic Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class BusinessLogicController : Controller {
    private readonly IStationController stationController;

    public BusinessLogicController(IStationController stationController) {
        this.stationController = stationController;
    }

    // Use the IStationController object in various calls
}
```

**Important (From documentation):**

*In the case of MVC, the fifth step (resolving the instance) is the responsibility of the MVC framework. For each received web requests, the MVC framework will map that request to a Controller type and ask the application’s IDependencyResolver to create an instance of that controller type. The registration of the SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver (part of the SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc.dll) will ensure that the request for creating an instance is forwarded on to Simple Injector. Simple Injector will create that controller with all of its nested dependencies.*

Comment: Hi Mrinal Kamboj this again requires my DI container reference in my bussineslogic class, and as far as i read on the internet this is not good.  Please let me know what you think of this statement.

Comment: I would advise against using a static `Factory`, and especially a factory that allows resolving _every type_, because that's an implementation of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) (Service Location is the opposite of _Dependency Injection_). Besides this, making it static makes consuming code hard to test and hides dependencies, and since the `Factory`'s assembly will have require a dependency on the DI Container, so will all consuming assemblies (since assembly dependencies are transitive).

Comment: Instead, in the very least, create an `IFactory<T>` interface that you inject into the constructor of a consumer. But you are right about pointing to the warning in the Simple Injector documentation. That warning stems from this [warning about factories in general](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100). With the current amount of detail of OP's question however, it's hard to to do an analysis of his current design and come up with an improvement that doesn't require the use of factories.

Comment: @Steven thanks for the points I did realize that my answer is having design mistakes, esepcially service locator anti pattern, but I was little confused due to lack of information available, now I have modified the same with relevant details related to MVC injection from the documentation. With an assumption that this would serve the OP purpose better

Comment: @Christophe, please have a look at the modified response, in case you have ASP.Net MVC architecture then this would serve the purpose better as it would automatically inject the dependency for a Web request

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thanks for the information i will apply this code when programming an MVC app.

Comment: @Steven the IFactory<T> suggestion does seem like a cleaner approach and would only require me to create 1 interface and 1 concrete implementation in my bootstrapper project for all my factory needs. Thanks.

Comment: @Christophe yes, but in that case, `Func <T>` would work as well and remember my advise on factories. You should have them as little as possible.

Comment: @Steven I think still there's lack of clarity, if we are using a Console / Non MVC app, then even for `IFactory<T>` and `Func<T>`, we need explicit injection from caller like `Container.Get<Hostclass>`, thereon it will fill the values being constructor injection and `Lifestyle.Transient` do take care of creating new object every time, so where is the benefit of using `Func<T>`, in fact MVC is the only one that allows automatic injection into the controller

Comment: Automatic constructor injection  (or auto-wiring) is a fwature provided by DI Containers sych as Simple Injector and Autofac. Without a DI Container we wire classes by hand (this partice.is called Pure DI) and we do this as part of our Composition Root. So it's not that MVC does auto-wiring, the used container will and these containers work in combination with all kinds of application types. They work equally well in a Console application.